# Shall this Regex do what I expect from it, that is, matching against "A1:B10,C3,D4:E1000"?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I'm currently writing a library where I wish to allow the user to be able to specify spreadsheet cell(s) under four possible alternatives:

1. A single cell: `"A1"`;
2. Multiple contiguous cells: `"A1:B10"`
3. Multiple separate cells: `"A1,B6,I60,AA2"`
4. A mix of 2 and 3: `"B2:B12,C13:C18,D4,E11000"`

Then, to validate whether the input respects these formats, I intended to use a regular expression to match against. I have consulted this article on Wikipedia:
[Regular Expression (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

And I also found this related SO question:
[regex matching alpha character followed by 4 alphanumerics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334123/regex-matching-alpha-character-followed-by-4-alphanumerics)

Based on the information provided within the above-linked articles, I would try with this Regex:

```
Default Readonly Property Cells(ByVal cellsAddresses As String) As ReadOnlyDictionary(Of String, ICell)
    Get
        Dim validAddresses As Regex = New Regex("A-Za-z0-9:,A-Za-z0-9")

        If (Not validAddresses.IsMatch(cellsAddresses)) then _
            Throw New FormatException("cellsAddresses")

        // Proceed with getting the cells from the Interop here...  
    End Get
End Property
```

> **Questions**

**1. Is my regular expression correct?** If not, please help me understand what expression I could use.

**2. What exception is more likely to be the more meaningful between a `FormatException` and an `InvalidExpressionException`?** I hesitate here, since it is related to the format under which the property expect the cells to be input, aside, I'm using an (regular) expression to match against.

Thank you kindly for your help and support! =)

Comment: Slightly off topic - When using regexes in .NET, it's usually best to use verbatim string literals: `@"foo"` instead of `"foo"`. Either one works fine in your example above, but if the string contains backslashes (as most regexes do), you'll have to either use a verbatim string or double all the backslashes: `@"\d"` matches any numeral, but without the `@` you'd have to write `"\\d"`. Hope that makes sense as I've written it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Justin His code is in VB.Net and string literals in VB are a bit different from their C# counterparts **in VB.Net you don't need to put @"foo"** before strings only character in VB that require excape is **"** in fact @ before string is a syntax error in VB.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the column for the spreadsheet is any 1- or 2-letter value and the row is any positive number, a more complex but tighter answer still would be:

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*(:[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*)?(,[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*(:[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*)?)*$
```

"[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*" is the expression for a single cell reference. If you replace "[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*" in the above with  then the complex expression becomes

```
^<cell>(:<cell>)?(,<cell>(:<cell>*)?)*$
```

which more clearly shows that it is a cell or a range followed by one or more "cell or range" entries with commas in between.

The row and column indicators could be further refined to give a tighter still, yet more complex expression. I suspect that the above could be simplified with look-ahead or look-behind assertions, but I admit those are not (yet) my strong suit.

Comment: +1 for mentioning about how to define one cell pattern plus the humility with which you say how this could be improved.

Comment: Lookarounds is a great thought, but I don't think they'll help in this exact situation. I think my answer might help, it's similar to yours but with a slight reordering of the items. There's a great regex lookaround reference here as well: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html BTW, +1 from me for the same reasons as @Will.

Comment: Oh, just to clarify - when I said they wouldn't help, I just meant that they wouldn't make it simpler/shorter. But having thought it through, I think I figured out a way. Check out my edit.

Comment: +1 for arriving there before me and my mistakenly replicating your answer without noticing. :)

Answer (score 4):

I would try this one:

```
 [A-Za-z]+[0-9]+([:,][A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)*
```

Explanation:

- Between [] is a possible group of characters for a single position
- [A-Za-z] means characters (letters) from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z'
- [0-9] means characters (digits) from 0 to 9
- A "+" appended to a part of a regex means: repeat that one or more times
- A "*" means: repeat the previous part zero or more times.
- `( )` can be used to define a group

So `[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+` matches one or more letters followed by one or more digits for a single cell-address.
Then that same block is repeated zero or more times, with a ',' or ':' separating the addresses.

Comment: The answer is far less complex than my own. My only concern is that it allows A1:B2:C3. Is there a way to avoid that without the added complexity that mine brings?

Comment: @DocMax - Hans did all the heavy lifting, but I believe this modified version of his express will protect against `A1:B2:C3`. Here is the mod `(([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[:][A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)|([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+))([,](([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[:][A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)|([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)))*`

Comment: @300, your version protects against A1:B2:C3 similarly to my own. I was just hoping to avoid repeating the "[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+" again and again, but I fear it cannot be avoided.

Comment: +1 Great explanation and pretty shorter approach. This solution seems to have won unanimously the privilege of everyone! =) I shall take an eye out to it.

Comment: @n00b32: I like your comment and humility. You must be a pretty nice person to know and to work with. Thanks for pointing me out what's best.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller: Thanks, you seem like a nice person too ;) @all: As an afterthought, this will match A00000000001 etc ... so i think `[A-Za-z]+[1-9][0-9]*` instead of `[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+`

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with this one, I think:

```
(([A-Z]+[1-9]\d*:)?[A-Z]+[1-9]\d*,)*([A-Z]+[1-9]\d*:)?[A-Z]+[1-9]\d*
```

This only allows capital letters as the prefix. If you want case insensitivity, use [**RegexOptions.IgnoreCase**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

You could simplify this by replacing `[A-Z]+[1-9]\d*` with plain old `[A-Z]\d+`, but that will only allow a one-letter prefix, and it also allows stuff like `A0` and `B01`. Up to you.

---

**EDIT:**

Having thought hard about **DocMax**'s mention of lookarounds, and using **Hans Kesting**'s answer as inspiration, it occurs to me that this should work:

```
^[A-Z]+\d+((,|(?<!:\w*):)[A-Z]+\d+)*$
```

Or if you want something **really** twisted:

```
^([A-Z]+\d+(,|$|(?<!:\w*):))*(?<!,|:)
```

As in the previous example, replace `\d+` with `[1-9]\d*` if you want to prevent leading zeros.

The idea behind the `,|(?<!\w*:):` is that if a group is delimited by a comma, you want to let it through; but if it's a colon, it's only allowed if the *previous* delimiter *wasn't* a colon. The `(,|$|...)` version is madness, but it allows you to do it all with only one `[A-Z]+\d+` block.

**However!** Even though this is shorter, and I'll admit I feel a *teeny* bit clever about it, I pity the poor fellow who has to come along and maintain it six months from now. It's fun from a code-golf standpoint, but I think it's best for practical purposes to go with the earlier version, which is a lot easier to read.

Comment: @DocMax: I think this might be the refinement you're looking for without the need for lookarounds. I've used lookarounds for delimited strings as well, but in this case I think they won't help. What they're really good for is simpler patterns like `^(?!,)(,?foo+)*$`.

Comment: +1 Nice option you mention there! This would then allow one to simplify in my opinion his regular expression by making it case insensitive, which I believe is the most common approach while using it.

Comment: Thanks for the look-behind solution! This is why I say that I really need to learn how to use those: once I start repeating a block I just feel that I am overlooking something. +1 from me.

Comment: @Justin Unfortunately, the "really twisted" version is prone to the same problems I bumped into trying to craft a more elegant solution with lookarounds. The moment you put begin/end string checks in an OR grouping, you start validating things that end the string with the options it ORs. i.e. the second solution would validate in the simplest case "B15," Your initial thought in the edit validates things like "B18:B19:B20" as well, unfortunately. Guess brute forcing it is probably the simplest. :[

Comment: @lthibodeaux - Hmm, the `(?<!,|:)` part was supposed to block exactly that from happening. It should require the line *not* to end on `,` or `;`. Have you tested it yet?

Comment: @Justin Actually, I think I've determined the problem with your initial edit answer. I just noticed the lookbehind assertion was formed in the incorrect order. Changing it to `(?<!:\w*)` would patch it up nicely!

Comment: @lthibodeaux - Great catch! And I suppose it boosts my point about overly "clever" regexes being so difficult to maintain. Edited as you suggested; give it a shot now.

Comment: @Justin I was actually playing with it before commenting and that was just the fix it needed. I'll be favoriting this post so I can have a look at that syntax later. It's really not all that nasty from where I'm sitting... might want to use something similar later. :]

Comment: @lthibodeaux - Cool, I'm happy to have made someone's favorites list! It may be useful to mention that you can do this with `^` and lookaheads, too, which is especially helpful in JavaScript where lookbehinds aren't supported.

Comment: Not going to lie, I'm still a bit floored that this monstrosity works.

Answer (score 1):

i think your regex is incorrect, try `(([A-Za-z0-9]*)[:,]?)*`

Edit : to correct the bug pointed out by Baud : `(([A-Za-z0-9]*)[:,]?)*([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

and finally - best version : `(([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)[:,]?)*([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)`

// ah ok this wont work probably... but to answer **1.** - no i dont think your regex is correct

**( )** form a group

**[ ]** form a charclass (you can use A-Z a-d 0-9 etc or just single characters)

**?** means 1 or 0

**`*`** means 0 or any

id suggest reading http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html .

thats where i learned regexes some time ago ;)

and for building expressions i use *[Rad Software Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/)*

Comment: I would take everything in one more brace and add a star at the end.

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing me to this regex. Can you please teach me what it means as in regards of the asterisk, square brackets and parenthesis characters? Thanks! =)

Comment: @MPekalski: Please provide further details as to why you would brace once more this whole expression. I'm a totally beginner in regards to regular expressions and I barely get them. Thanks! =)

Comment: @MPekalski: true, corrected. @Will: without it, it would match 1 cell, ended (or not) by , or :

Comment: @n00b32: My sincerest thanks for your answer. I shall now unit test it and see whether this does what I want and if it does, I'll be back to accept your answer. =)

Comment: i hope it works in .NET i dont know how well microsoft implemented regex :P

Comment: This pattern will pass an expression that ends in a `:` or `,` i.e. `A1,` will pass this pattern

Answer (score 1):

Let's build this step by step.

If you are following an Excel addressing format, to match a single-cell entry in your CSL, you would use the regular expression:

```
[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*
```

This matches the following in sequence:

```
Any character in A to Z once or twice
Any digit in 1 to 9
Any digit zero or more times
```

The digit expression will prevent inputting a cell address with leading zeros.

To build the expression that allows for a cell address pair, repeat the expression preceded by a colon as optional.

```
[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*(:[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*)?
```

Now allow for repeating the pattern preceded by a comma zero or more times and add start and end string delimiters.

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*(:[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*)?(,[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*(:[A-Z]{1,2}[1-9]\d*)?)*$
```

Kind of long and obnoxious, I admit, but after trying enough variants, I can't find a way of shortening it.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your hard work trying different variants. I'm still somehow unit testing my code that interacts with the underlying spreadsheet cells. I shall let you know how you helped me when I'm done.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a quick JavaScript test utility: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/Gm95c/).

Comment: Actually, looking up, turns out my revision just turned into Docmax's answer. If we both arrived there separately, this is probably the holy grail, heh.