# check that text is 3 upper case alphas followed by 5 numeric digits before inserting into database

Tags: java, android, string, char

I need to check user input from an EditText against the pattern described before inserting it into my database. If it doesnt matchI want to pop up an error message for the user. Is there an easier way of doing this than this:

```
public boolean myCheckMethod()
{
 String s = myEditText.getText.toString();
 if(s.length!=8)
  return false;
 for(int i=0; i < 8; i++){
  if(i < 3)
   if(!(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
    return false;
  if(i > 3)
   if(!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
    return false;
 }

 return true;
}
```

There HAS to be a better way of doing this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is:

```
if(s.matches("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}"))
  return true;
return false;
```

Then use that method in an if statement when you add to your database:

```
if(myCheckMethod())
{
  //code to add to db here
}
else
  Toast
    .makeText(this, "User error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
```

Comment: It worked!! It even catches  the ones that are not 8 chars!  Brilliant; that matches method saves lives :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not unreasonable. You could also test with a regular expression. Maybe something like `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}`. There might be problems with unusual characters in non-English languages though. Not sure if it matters in your case.

Answer (score 0):

REGEX is the way to go.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334123/regex-matching-alpha-character-followed-by-4-alphanumerics) answer.  Not exactly your case but good explanations.

[This](http://www.regextester.com/) will help

[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4} is one possible pattern but as with all things regex, someone else will answer with a better pattern ;)

But you get the idea...

Cheers

P.S.  Sorry for the dupes, by the time I pressed post, I was way down the heap...