# How to use Regex in c# for the following situation

Tags: c#, regex

I have a textbox in which when the user tries to enter a word the format should only begin with 'PHY' followed by 8 digit numbers.

For example,

The correct format is `PHY00000000`

In here the first three letters 'PHY' is constant and the next 8 digit numbers vary from 00000000 to 10000000.

How to get this format using regex condition? No other format should be supported.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Are you sure that's 00,000,000 to 10,000,000 and not 99,999,99?

Comment: http://www.marksanborn.net/howto/learning-regular-expressions-for-beginners-the-basics/

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex matching alpha character followed by 4 alphanumerics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334123/regex-matching-alpha-character-followed-by-4-alphanumerics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want regular expression for values range from `PHY00000000` to `PHY10000000`, you should use:

```
PHY[0-1]\d{7}
```

But I do not like this, as we are trying to interpret value of number using regular expression. I would use them to split this input and interpret it as a number with specified range (then you can easily change this valid range of numbers):

```
static bool Valid(string input)
{
    const string Pattern = @"PHY(\d{8})";
    const int Max = 10000000;

    var match = Regex.Match(input, Pattern);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        int value = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        if (value <= Max)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So you can take `Pattern` and `Max` from some configuration etc.

Comment: Also allows values greater than 10000000. Therefore, not meeting the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In order to take care of the requirements, the following regex expression will work:

```
const string match = "PHY(0\d{7}|1(0){7})";
```

You then can validate the input by a simple method:

```
bool ValidateInput(string input)
{
    var regex = new Regex(match);
    return regex.IsMatch(input);
}
```